# How to have multiple bin folders in an asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, bin

I have an asp.net application located in C:/MainApp which has a bin folder. In IIS I have configured this as a web application and I can run my test pages.

Now, I have 2 web service applications with their own dlls and I don't want to deploy those dlls in the main bin folder c:/MainApp/Bin for some reasons, please don't ask why! These 2 subapps need to be hosted under the same MainApp without creating a new Virtual Folder for each.

So,

```
c:/MainApp
c:/MainApp/bin
c:/MainApp/SubApp1/bin
c:/MainApp/SubApp2/bin
```

How to configure the webconfig so that my SubApp folders can have their own bin folders?

If so, would they inherit from the MainApp bin folder also at runtime?

many thanks,

Answer (score 7):

You can add an assemblyBinding element to your web.config to set multiple 'bin' paths:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>   
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;SubApp1\bin;SubApp2\bin"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>   
</configuration>
```

This will cause your main web application to use DLLs from all of the bin paths in the `probing` element.

Comment: Thanks, I added this but it says the type could not be found. Is there anything else I'd need to do?

Comment: Are these SubApp folders actually located under the application folder, or are they just virtual directories?  If the latter, you'll need to put their full path, not relative path.

Comment: Yes, they seem to be under a virtual folder though I tried both absolute url path and absolute physical path of the bin folder but same issue.

Comment: Not sure whats going on there then.  That should work, with the physical path.

Comment: If my SubApp1 is located somewhere else physically e.g. D://SubApp2 then added to the MainApp as virtual directory in IIS, then how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a Bin folder yourself in the **root folder** of the website in IIS
2- Search for *.dll in your project and paste the DLLs in the Bin folder created in step 1 (it will find all the dlls inside inner bin folders)

i have fixed my missed assemblies in asp.net ckfinder + ckeditor apps hosted in IIS for testing