# Web API Deploy with .DLLs in folder other than BIN

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

When manually deploying Web API (MVC) to a site, can I have all .DLLs not in BIN folder but in some other folder (e.g. BIN2)?
Is there a setting in Web.config for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057526/how-to-have-multiple-bin-folders-in-an-asp-net-application

Comment: @WilliamXifaras  Thank you.  The thread you referenced is very helpful.